# Helper mac app (Login Item), unable to communicate with

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I've done exactly as the Sandboxed Helper App example provided by Apple and all seems to be running fine. I'm able to successfully create a `NSXPCConnection` object and also get back my remote object (via `remoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler`).

However when I call a method on the proxy object (defined in the Protocol definition), I get back this error:

```
Failed to connect to launch agent: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.
```

Essentially no matter what I do I'm not able to communicate with my helper app. I'm doing nothing fancy, just trying to make a simple call to the helper app to NSLog() something. But it doesn't work. Strangely I also don't see any output from inside:

```
- (BOOL)listener:(NSXPCListener *)listener shouldAcceptNewConnection:(NSXPCConnection *)newConnection
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Apparently if I uncheck 'Enable App Sandboxing' on my main app, it works! So there's something wrong with enabling sandboxing after which it does not want to communicate with my helper app. Do I need more entitlements? I've tried them all under xcode!

Comment: If you open the console, do you get a sandbox mach lookup violation ?

Comment: No, but I found a solution, explained below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your helper application is sandboxed. Therefore, it cannot register a mach service dynamically, although Xcode allows it for debug purpose.

However, when you add your helper application to login items (using SMLoginItemSetEnabled() ), launchd will automatically register a mach service for you named with its bundle identifier.

Now your main application is sandboxed. Therefore, random mach communication is not allowed. The only way to make it work was to add a temporary mach lookup entitlement.

Since 10.7.4. Apple introduced the application-groups entitlements as a solution for this case, where an application needs to communicate with a helper app.

Both applications have to share the same application-groups entitlement. It can be any value, but Apple requires that this value must start with your Team-ID (e.g: Team-id.myApp). Then, your helper application bundle identifier must start with that same entitlement (e.g Team-id.myApp.myHelperApp). After that, your main application can freely communicate with your helper application using a XPC communication with the service named with the helper application bundle identifier (i.e. Team-id.myApp.myHelperApp). Also, the two applications will share access to a group container folder named with the application group entitlement (e.g. ~/Library/Group Containers/Team-id.myApp), that you have to create manually if you will need it.

Comment: I've marked your reply as the correct response to the problem. Although my efforts lead me to the same discovery, you've explained it very well. The only problem now is that with Xcode 5.0 it won't codesign my helper app and complains that the TEAM-ID.com.mycompany.myapp does NOT match the 'com.mycompany.myapp' provisioning profile. I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I am a little bit further, I can code sign the helper in Xcode 5, and it does launch and I can communicate via XPC, but the kernel posts code signing errors despite codesign showing a valid signature on the executable.  Further, attempts to attach to the helper crash Xcode (reported to bugreporter already)

Answer (score 4):

Okay so I've learned the hard way - there are tons of issues with Sandboxing and XPC not to mention helper apps and sharing databases using the so called 'shared group directory' which neither gets created automatically (as the documentation incorrectly says) nor does `NSURL` offer the method it claims to in the documentation.

Although the documentation says that in the Entitlements you can specify any string as the 'shared app identifier' in the format `<TEAM_ID>.whatever`, apparently it will ONLY work if you use the format: `<TEAM_ID>.com.yourcompany`

Anything else and it won't work. It'll compile, it'll archive, it'll run but it won't let you talk to your helper app. After spending around 30 hours I thought heck I'll try that one last change and apparently that was it! Filing a radar on the horribly written sandboxing documentation (which a lot on Apple's Developer forum are complaining about) next...

Comment: One valuable source of information about xpc connections is the man page (type man xpc_connection_create in your terminal)

Comment: @strange could you look at my question on SO about this same issue and see if you can help me - see: AVPlayer won't let me access URL